# Eval in android native, how to go about it

Tags: android, android-ndk

We are developing an app in android, but it seems that it is impossible to use the eval function ( there is no eval function ). We need to specify and tweak algorithms for this app ( and set different variables), but without the eval function what would be the best way to go about it ?
We do not use java.

Comment: So basically you want `eval` for your C++ code? Maybe you'll be pleased with [scripting](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Tutorials) embedded into your app?

Comment: If you do not use Java, which language are you using for your android app?

Comment: We use c++ for our development